# Selecting data from table where sum of values in a column equal to the value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sample data:

```
create table #temp (id int, qty int, checkvalue int)
insert into #temp values (1,1,3)
insert into #temp values (2,2,3)
insert into #temp values (3,1,3)
insert into #temp values (4,1,3)
```

According to data above, I would like to show exact number of lines from top to bottom where `sum(qty) = checkvalue`. Note that checkvalue is same for all the records all the time. Regarding the sample data above, the desired output is:

```
Id Qty checkValue
1   1     3
2   2     3
```

Because 1+2=3 and no more data is needed to show. If checkvalue was 4, we would show the third record: `Id:3 Qty:1 checkValue:4` as well.

This is the code I am handling this problem. The code is working very well.

```
declare @checkValue int = (select top 1 checkvalue from #temp);
declare @counter int = 0, @sumValue int = 0;

while @sumValue < @checkValue
begin
    set @counter = @counter + 1;
    set @sumValue = @sumValue + (
                                    select t.qty from
                                    (
                                        SELECT * FROM (
                                          SELECT
                                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownumber,
                                            id,qty,checkvalue
                                          FROM #temp
                                        ) AS foo
                                        WHERE rownumber = @counter
                                    ) t
    )
end

declare @sql nvarchar(255) = 'select top '+cast(@counter as varchar(5))+' * from #temp'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@counter int', @counter = @counter;
```

However, I am not sure if this is the best way to deal with it and wonder if there is a better approach. There are many professionals here and I'd like to hear from them about what they think about my approach and how we can improve it. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Sum of `Qty's` for rows 2 and 3 is also 3. Why you are not expecting them in result?

Comment: Not aiming to see all rows providing qty+qty+... = 3 here. From top to bottom, I am showing data if sum(qty) < 3. No more data we need to show when this condition is provided

Comment: Annoyingly, this would be trivial if you were using SQL Server 2012 onwards. I assume there is no option for using a later (supported) version?

Comment: You can actually use subquery with `sum over`  like this and check    `select id,qty,checkvalue from 
(select *, sum(qty) over( order by id) Rowsum  from @temp) x
where Rowsum<=checkvalue`

Comment: if checkvalue was 2, what would you expect as a result?

Comment: @Larnu, please do share what you have. Even if OP themselve cannot utilize it now, it doesn't rule out them getting a chance to utilize it later, or other readers benefiting from it.

Comment: Also, @ErayBalkanli, please note ambiguity of phrasing. Your question states "*exact number of lines*", "*where sum(qty) = checkvalue*", while your comment states "*if sum (qty) < 3*", as well as answerer uzi understanding "*where sum of QTY <= checkvalue*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, qty, checkvalue from (
    select t1.*,
           sum(t1.qty) over (partition by t2.id) [sum]
from #temp [t1] join #temp [t2] on t1.id <= t2.id
) a where checkvalue = [sum]
```

Smart self-join is all you need :)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2012, and onwards, you can easily achieve this using `ROWS BETWEEN` in your `OVER` clause and the use of a CTE:

```
WITH Running AS(
    SELECT *,
           SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY id
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningQty
    FROM #temp t)
SELECT id, qty, checkvalue
FROM Running
WHERE RunningQty <= checkvalue;
```

Comment: Yeah, would be nice if I use 2012.. Thanks for sharing tho, upvoting ;)

Answer (score 0):

One basic improvement is to try & reduce the no. of iterations. You're incrementing by 1, but if you repurpose the logic behind binary searching, you'd get something close to this:

```
DECLARE @RoughAverage int = 1 -- Some arbitrary value. The closer it is to the real average, the faster things should be.
DECLARE @CheckValue int = (SELECT TOP 1 checkvalue FROM #temp)
DECLARE @Sum int = 0

WHILE 1 = 1 -- Refer to BREAK below.
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@RoughAverage) @Sum = SUM(qty) OVER(ORDER BY id)
    FROM #temp
    ORDER BY id

    IF @Sum = @CheckValue
        BREAK -- Indicating you reached your objective.
    ELSE
        SET @RoughAverage = @CheckValue - @Sum -- Most likely incomplete like this.
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2008 you can use `recursive cte`. `Top 1 with ties` limits result with first combination. Remove it to see all combinations

```
with cte as (
    select 
        *, rn = row_number() over (order by id)
    from 
        #temp
)
, rcte as (
    select
        i = id, id, qty, sumV = qty, checkvalue, rn
    from
        cte
    union all
    select
        a.id, b.id, b.qty, a.sumV + b.qty, a.checkvalue, b.rn
    from
        rcte a
        join cte b on a.rn + 1 = b.rn
    where
        a.sumV < b.checkvalue
)

select
    top 1 with ties id, qty, checkvalue
from (
    select 
        *, needed = max(case when sumV = checkvalue then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by i) 
    from 
        rcte
) t
where
    needed = 1
order by dense_rank() over (order by i)
```

Comment: it might fix the issue, but still looking as complex as my query :)

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, query might be complex but this is because of your condition. Actually your accepted answer is not correct. At least several cases are not handled correctly. Here is a sample http://rextester.com/KCVU88511

Comment: @uzi, perhaps you should leave a comment on the incorrect answer. Also, while I didn't read OP's code, his described requirement is incomplete, as it does not clarify what happens when the top-to-bottom summation jumps over the target (*your linked dataset being an example*). Hence, it seems like a problem in the question, not the answer.

Comment: @KtX2SkD, looks like OP wants to get rows from 1 where sum of `QTY <= checkvalue`. While I misunderstood and was looking for exact match. So, for his case accepted answer is better option